# Check for authentication, output different nav?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to include a different nav if the user is logged in. I need to do this in my view (I know the logic should really go elsewhere but I need it here).

```
 @include( {{ Auth::guest() ? 'nav-a' : 'nav-b' }} )
```

The above fails to work:

```
development.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')''
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you are working in the confines of an `@` statement, php is already assumed.

```
@include( Auth::guest() ? 'nav-a' : 'nav-b' )
```